# How can I convert json into the right format using PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE?

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

I get data from my mySQL database via pdo:

```
$people = $db->query('SELECT * FROM people ORDER BY id ASC;')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE);
```

The array `people` looks like this:

```
array(84) {
  [40]=>
  array(12) {
    ["name"]=>string(5) "Tiger Nixon"
    [0]=> string(5) "Tiger Nixon"
    ["positon"]=> string(7) "System Architect"
    [1]=> string(7) "System Architect"
    ["salary"]=> string(10) "$320,800"
    [2]=> string(10) "$320,800"
    ["start_date"]=> string(11) "2011/04/25"
    [3]=> string(11) "2011/04/25"
    ["office"]=> string(5) "Edinburgh"
    [4]=> string(5) "Edinburgh"
    ["extn"]=> string(5) "5421"
    [5]=> string(5) "5421"

  }
  [41]=>
   array(12) {
    ["name"]=> string(5) "Garrett Winters"
    [0]=> string(5) "Garrett Winters"
    ["positon"]=> string(7) "Accountant"
    [1]=> string(7) "Accountant"
    ["salary"]=> string(10) "$170,750"
    [2]=> string(10) "$170,750"
    ["start_date"]=> string(11) "2011/07/25"
    [3]=> string(11) "2011/07/25"
    ["office"]=> string(5) "Tokyo"
    [4]=> string(5) "Tokyo"
    ["extn"]=> string(5) "8422"
    [5]=> string(5) "8422"
  }
...
```

if I convert this now into json via `echo json_encode($people);`

The result is:

```
{"40":{
    "name":"Tiger Nixon",
    "0":"Tiger Nixon",
    "position":"System Architect",
    "1":"System Architect",
    "salary":"$320,800",
    "2":"$320,800",
    "start_date":"2011/04/25",
    "3":"2011/04/25",
    "office":"Edinburgh",
    "4":"Edinburgh",
    "extn":"5421",
    "5":"5421",
   },
...
```

But this is not the format I need. Actually I need this format:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Tiger Nixon",
    "position": "System Architect",
    "salary": "$320,800",
    "start_date": "2011/04/25",
    "office": "Edinburgh",
    "extn": "5421"
  },
  {
    "name": "Garrett Winters",
    "position": "Accountant",
    "salary": "$170,750",
    "start_date": "2011/07/25",
    "office": "Tokyo",
    "extn": "8422"
  },
...
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you should tell `fetchAll()` that you want an assoc array returned and not both the assoc array and a numeric array.

```
->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE|PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
```

Comment: Great! But there is still a number before:  `{"40":{
    "name": "Tiger Nixon",
    "position": "System Architect",
    "salary": "$320,800",
    "start_date": "2011/04/25",
    "office": "Edinburgh",
    "extn": "5421"
  }`

Comment: I think it works best if I use only `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`